# Vue with PHP server OAuth2 good practice

Tags: php, vue.js, oauth-2.0

I'm using PHP code https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/grant-types/ for my OAuth2 logic. What are best practices to use OAuth2 validation when combining with Vue framework. I've read that Implicit grant type was used, but it is not anymore because of security reasons. Is there any good guide with proper way of using OAuth2 for it?

Comment: _"Is there any good guide"_ - I'm sure there is if you do some extensive research. Meanwhile, [asking for tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If your thinking about being a OAuth or Authentication server or provider rather than using OAuth to athenticate with a third party server. I would suggest you start and end with [Gluu](https://www.gluu.org/), plus they have amazing documentation.